# WPF ShowDialog with another Window Active

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

When my MainWindow starts, I automatically show a 2nd "CountdownWindow".  The CountdownWindow is TopMost.

[image: MainWindow and CoutdownWindow]

While both the Main and Countdown windows are shown the user can click a button to launch a 3rd Modal Window with ShowDialog.

[image: Dialog window is active but CountdownWindow is not]

While the Dialog is active, I would like the user to be able to also interact with the topmost CountdownWindow (i.e., minimize, maximize, close it or move it around), however this is not possible.

Would launching the Dialog window from a separate process or a separate thread solve this problem?

Here are the relevant parts of my code if you need it

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialogWindow = new DialogWindow();
        dialogWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var countDownWindow = new CountdownWindow();
        countDownWindow.Owner = this;
        countDownWindow.Show();
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfTestBase.CountdownWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestBase"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Topmost="True"
    Title="CountdownWindow TopMost=True" Height="300" Width="400">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I think ShowDialog is not async - it blocks the main thread. That causes your entire application to block until ShowDialog returns.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Dialog.ShowDialog() why don't you just set the Dialog.Owner = MainWindow, then Dialog.Show()? It will then stay on top of the main window, but will not block the main thread as it does with ShowDialog(). The whole point of ShowDialog is to be modal, and block the main UI thread.

Comment: Doing that allows the user to interact with the CountdownWindow while the DialogWindow is open which is great.  However it allows the user to interact with the MainWindow while the DialogWindow is open which is not the behaviour we want.

Comment: It sounds like you just don't want the user interacting with the MainWindow while the CountdownWindow is open. When you open then CountdownWindow from the MainWindow, you could set MainWindow.IsEnabled = false. This will keep the user from interacting with the MainWindow. Then you could create a handler for the CountdownWindow.Closing event. In that event handler you could set MainWindow.IsEnabled = true to restore access to the MainWindow. This way you wouldn't even need the dialog window.

Comment: I need the DialogWindow which has several controls the user needs (not shown here to keep the example short). 
 Before the DialogWindow is shown, I do actually want the user to interact with the MainWindow and the CountdownWindow at the same time